# How to check the existance of a Loganalytic alertrule using azure CLI

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Is there any way to check the existance of a Loganalytic rule by the alertrulename using Az commands or shell script. Looking for some solution where I can check whether the given alertrule name in Azuredevops pipeline runtime paramenter is existing in Azure , if existing skip and if not existing create the alert rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can view all the log alerts in a resource group using the following command:

```
az monitor scheduled-query list -g {ResourceGroup}
```

For more info please refer [Manage log alerts using CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log#manage-log-alerts-using-cli).

Comment: but how can verify if a partucular alertrule is existing and capture the output, and do the creation only if its not present.

Comment: This is all monitor related Azure CLI commands for your reference：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor?view=azure-cli-latest  How did you get the alertrule name in Azure devops pipeline runtime paramenter? you can list the existing alert names and create a new one if it doesn't exist after comparing. (maybe using if... else... ).